Opening Dialog Inside DropDownMenu Shadcn UI React JS
I am trying to have a button in my DropDownMenu from Shadcn UI that opens a Dialog component.
I have two options.

I trigger the Dialog from the DropDownMenuItem component
I trigger the Dialog from a separate Button component

OPTION 1 PROBLEM
The DropDownMenu & Dialog are closed immediately simultaneously
OPTION 2 PROBLEM
The DropDownMenu remains open
Here is my minimal example code for option 1; Does anyone have a solution?
<DropdownMenu>
  <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
    <Button>Trigger Dropdown</Button>
  </DropdownMenuTrigger>
  <DropdownMenuContent>
    <DropdownMenuLabel>Organisation</DropdownMenuLabel>
    <DropdownMenuItem>
      <Dialog>
        <DialogTrigger>
          <Button>Trigger Dialog</Button>
        </DialogTrigger>
        <DialogContent>{...dialogContent}</DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    </DropdownMenuItem>
  </DropdownMenuContent>
</DropdownMenu>;


How about moving the Dialog out of the DropdownMenuItem and use the Dialog without a trigger and then use the open/onOpenChange props on the Dialog? The DropdownMenuItem would then onClick set the open state of the dialog to true
